# Is there any way to make sure the output of the float-point the same in different OS?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, io, floating-point

Here is my code：

```
int a = 0x451998a0;
float b = *((float *)&a);
printf("coverto float: %f, %.10lf\n", b, b);
```

In windows the output is:

```
coverto float: 2457.539063, 2457.5390625000
```

In linux the output is:

```
coverto float: 2457.539062, 2457.5390625000
```

Is there any way to make sure the output is the same?

Comment: Q: Why do you need them to be the same? Note that `%f` prints a `double` and `%lf` prints a `long double`. `float` is promoted to `double` when passed to a variable-length argument list, so the first argument is OK. But the second argument causes UB, except that fortunately `double` and `long double` are of the same length on your platform.

Comment: @ybungalobill  My application runs in windows, there are a lot data, maybe million lines, write to file. And I will run the same logic in Linux and write to file too, to check the log in windows is correct.When I use svn diff these output "different" disturb me to find the real different, So I want to make sure the output is the same.

Comment: One printf rounds up in case of tie, the over rounds tie to nearest even (aka banker rounding).

Comment: Try setting the floating point rounding mode on the Linux side to FE_TONEAREST or FE_UPWARD using fesetround().

Comment: @ybungalobill: `%lf` is equivalent to `%f` when used with `printf`.  For `long double` you need `%Lf`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: what in the world makes you think that?  Quoting C11 §7.21.6.1: "`L` Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a `long double` argument." and "`l` ... has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier."

Comment: @StephenCanon: You're correct, I remembered it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The behavior you're seeing is just a consequence of the fact that Windows' `printf()` function is implemented differently from Linux's `printf()` function. Most likely the difference is in how `printf()` implements number rounding.

How `printf()` works under the hood in either system is an implementation detail; thus the system is not likely to provide such fine-grained control on how `printf()` displays the floating point values.

There are two ways that may work to keep them the same:

1. Use more precision during calculation than while displaying it. For example, some scientific and graphing calculators use `double` precision for all internal calculations, but display the results with only `float` precision.
2. Use a cross-platform `printf()` library. Such libraries would most likely have the same behavior on all platforms, as the calculations required to determine what digits to display are usually platform-agnostic.

However, this really isn't as big of a problem as you think it is. The difference between the outputs is 0.000001. That is a ~0.0000000004% difference from either the two values. The display error is really quite negligible.

Consider this: [the distance between Los Angeles and New York is 2464 miles](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=the+distance+between+Los+Angeles+and+New+York), which is of the same order of magnitude as the numbers in your display outputs. A difference of 0.000001 miles is 1.61 *millimeters*. We of course don't measure distances between cities with anywhere near that kind of precision. :-)

Comment: @In silico Thanks for your answer. I'm just curious is there any way to make sure the output the same.

Comment: @hdbean: you can use a 3rd party library that implements floating point formatting on all platforms in the same way (assuming `double` means ieee754 binary64 on all of them).

Comment: @hdbean: Not in current systems, no. As ybungalobill has mentioned, you can use a 3rd party cross-platform floating-point library. But don't worry, air traffic computers are not going to cause plane crashes because their displays had a 0.000001 mile difference. :-)

Comment: In silico: this misses the point... sometimes getting exact matches simplifies regression testing (whether on one platform or across them), run-time assertions etc.

Comment: @ybungalobill Could you me a 3td pary lib will work fine and be simple, I just need the output part.

Comment: @In silico  Could you me a 3td pary lib will work fine and be simple, I just need the output part.

Comment: @hdbean http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c does exactly what you want. The dtoa function converts a double to a string, similar to the standard fcvt function but does it in a minimal precise and platform independent way.

Comment: @Tony Delroy: You're doing regression tests wrong then. Such tests should be  examining the actual floating-point value, not a display of the floating-point value. The regression tests for floating-point value display are written by the implementators of `printf()`, not by users of `printf()`.

Comment: Exact matching of floating point values is a wrong way for regression test. Use relative difference instead of them.

Comment: @In silico: that's equally unhelpful... it's not unusual to have only some log files or XML output and want to do a diff for testing purposes, and spurious differences don't help.  Of course you can complicate your comparison tools to cope, but who wants to have to?  Getting high and mighty about whether they're significant or the comparison should conceptually be done pre-rendering doesn't stop it being an extra burden of time and effort...

Comment: @Tony Delroy: What's also equally unhelpful is your apparent unwillingness to acknowledge the fact that floating point is subject to rounding issues no matter how you deal with it. If your code or your tests depends on the *exact* digits displayed then you're doing it wrong, period. There's no point in making something easy if it leads to wrong results. Even if you use the exact same `printf()` for all platforms, your tests are screwed the moment you need to use a different library for some reason. Assuming that the floating point output will be the *exact* same will make your code brittle.

Comment: @In silico: again, you're seeing this from the perspective of someone writing new code, and handling the comparison inside C++ tests.  Say you have a huge mass of existing code, you may want to port it Linux->Windows or vice versa and verify the textual outputs match.  There can be some value in that, and using a specific `printf()` implementation during that migration may be an easy win productivity wise.  It's just wrong to assume the questioner can never have a sound use for this and refuse to answer the question as asked.  By all means put your "be careful about this" as a comment/aside...

Comment: @Tony Delroy: I don't see how any of scenarios you put forward are valid reasons. If you wish to continue this discussion in one of SO's chat rooms, you may do so. I will not comment further on this post.

Comment: @In silico: no - doesn't bother me... any readers who have such a use will understand where I'm coming from and make their own decision....

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same printf() implementation, there's a good chance they'll show the same output.  Depending on what you're up to, it may be easier to use GNU GCC on both OSes, or to get printf() source code and add it to your project (you should have no trouble googling one).

BTW - have you actually checked what that hex number encodes?  Should it round up or down?  The 625 thing is likely itself rounded, so you shouldn't assume it should round to 63....

Comment: We can check in Smalltalk, 2457.5390625 asFraction -> (314565/128), only 19 bits for numerator, a power of two at denominator - so that is the exact value of the float, and since 128=2^7 we need 7 digits after fraction

Comment: `2457.5390625` is exact; since it is an exact halfway case, it *should* by default (per IEEE-754) round to the nearest even: `2457.539062`.  This has never been handled correctly on windows, however; they chose to round ties away from zero for some unknown reason, giving `2457.539063` instead.  I hesitate to call it a bug, because it's a deliberate choice on their part.

Comment: @StephenCanon: You cannot call it a bug since the C standard requires correct rounding only in the "Recommended Practice" section, and even then it does not say that "correct" means IEEE-754.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use less precision in your output.  In general,
if there's any calculation involved, you can't even be sure that the
actual floating point values are identical.  And how `printf` and
`ostream` round is implementation defined, even if the floating point
values are equal.

In general, C++ doesn't guarantee that two implementations produce the
same results.  In this particular case, *if* it's important, you can do
the rounding by hand, before doing the conversion, but you'll still have
occasional problems because the actual floating point values will be
different.  This may, in fact, occur even with different levels of
optimization with the same compiler.  So anything you try (other than
writing the entire program in assembler) is bound to be a loosing battle
in the end.

Comment: As illustrated in the question, the conversion is done from the same binary encoded number... so it's applicable to say `printf()`-ing a number received in a binary network packet or file. In that case, the rounding/calculation/order-of-evaluation/optimisation etc. concerns are avoided. Of course, the question may be simplified and those concerns may still be relevant to "hdbean", so your insights are useful background knowledge.